# Porque meu option não mantém selecionado mesmo com o atributo selected="selected"?

Tags: angularjs

Estou trabalhando com angular e tenho o seguinte select

```
<select ng-change="$ctrl.calculateDescount(partnerIndex,item)" ng-model="item.offerDiscountId" class="form-control" ng-if="item.view_offer">
                    <option value="">(Selecione uma Promoção)</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="offer in item.offers.data" ng-if="item.subtotal > offer.purchaseLimit" value="{{offer.id}}" ng-selected="item.idOffer == offer.id">{{item.idOffer}} {{offer.id}}</option>
                  </select>
```

Verificando no console a segunda opção está com o atributo selected inserido pelo angular a partir da condição `ng-selected` como deveria. Mas não mantém selecionado exibindo a opção "(Selecione uma Promoção)".

```
<option ng-repeat="offer in item.offers.data" ng-selected="item.idOffer == offer.id" ng-if="item.subtotal > offer.purchaseLimit" value="30182" class="ng-binding ng-scope" selected="selected">30182 30182 </option>
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por esse tipo de problema e como resolveu? já que mesmo com o atributo selected não está respeitando.

Comment: Veja: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected

Comment: esse que é a questão Marconi mesmo com o atributo selected para indicar qual deve ficar selecionado ele não seleciona.

Comment: O seu select está meio estranho.. você setou como model nele `item.offerDiscountId`, logo esse deve ser o valor selecionado no `option`, mas lá você está usando `item.idOffer` para marcar o item selecionado. Já tentou mudar para isso: `ng-selected="item.offerDiscountId == offer.id"`?

Comment: É isso mesmo, de acordo com a documentação o ngSelected não interage com ngModel. Ele serve apenas como indicador de seleção. o item.idOffer é o valor que vem do banco de dados após ser selecionado. a verificação está sendo feita corretamente e o angular está adicionando selected="selected"  na tag. Mas não está mantendo selecionado após a página ser carregada como falei https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected a mudança que vc sugeriu também não funciona.

Comment: @MiguelBatista O código que você nos apresentou está correto, você pode colocar o código do `controller` ou colocar em um fiddle e também mandar um print da sua inspeção onde mostra que há um `option` com atributo `selected="selected"`. Talvez esteja acontecendo algo após o "evento" de seleção.